# Do we really use TestNG Parallel run mode for web tests execution?

Tags: selenium, parallel-processing, testng

I have developed some web tests using selenium and I am trying the TestNG parallel option.

```
<test parallel="methods"  thread-count="5" name="Test">
```

Since these are completely web tests, since the thread count is 5 it is opening 5 browsers and the results are totally wrong. I expect this, because even though it opens 5 browsers, it can work with only one browser at a time.

So the question is, do we really use this option for web testing?

If not, where can we use this? Please give some examples.

Thank you.

Comment: How does your setup look like? Can you post some small example that fails? Unless you are using static/singleton variables (or Explorer) it should not be a problem - at least in theory.

Comment: Please share tests classes...

Comment: @Subbu Is this issue solved for u? :)

Answer (score 1):

try developing independent tests if you are running in parallel, some good information is at
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running